# How to save the log messages into the text file

Tags: c++

I am currently doing on the timestamp on the robot and I have managed to display the results on it. However, I would like to know on how to save the information to the text file. I am currently using C++ compiler

```
const std::string currentDateTime() {
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm  tstruct;
    char       buf[80];
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);

    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d %X", &tstruct);

    return buf;
   
    std::cout << currentDateTime() << " Robot 1" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing to `std::cout` you can print to a [std::ofstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/):

```
#include <fstream>

std::ofstream logfile("logfile", std::ofstream::out); // or std::ofstream::app to append
logfile << currentDateTime() << " Robot 1" << std::endl
```

Maybe you want to add error checking in case the logfile cannot be openend/created.

Comment: Hi, if for instance, i want to save this text file into a specific directory, how do i do that?For example, i want to save it in a robot folder

Comment: The first argument to the constructor is the path to the file. You can specify any path there.

Comment: @DanielJunglas I'm not sure your answer is fully correct. I'd say the path can be any existing path, except the file itself. `ofstream` constructor won't create the necessary folder structure, it only creates the file if it's not created yet.

Comment: I guess this is a wording issue: you can specify any path. Whether opening the file at that path succeeds is a different question. It will definitely fail if the path to the file does not exist. It may still fail even if the path exists. So yes, to be clear: the constructor may create the file but it will not create any intermediate missing directories.

Comment: I have followed your code and I found that I can only save one reading in a file. However, is there a way to store multiple readings in a text file as I have multiple data?

Comment: Did you try opening the file with `std::ofstream::app` instead of `std::ofstream::out`? Maybe also check the documentation I pointed to. It explains the several ways in which you can open a file.

Comment: I just tried out the std::ofstream::app and it works perfectly fine! Thank you so much :)